# Uploading files with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, form-data

I am attempting to upload an image via AJAX using a simple HTML form including a `input[type='file']` element, and `formData()`, however when I inspect `formData()` it appears to be empty, and nothing is being passed to the server.

**jQuery**

```
//Dynamically loaded form

$(document).on('submit', '.update-form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    amendDatabase(form);
});

function amendDatabase(form) {
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    console.log(formData); //This produces 'formData: No properties'

    var url = 'file.php';

    request = $.ajax({
        url:            url,
        method:         'post',
        data:           formData,
        processData:    false,
        contentType:    false
    });

    request.done(function(data) {
        console.log(data); //This produces an empty/blank return
    });
}
```

**file.php**

```
function uploadFile() {
    echo 'formData was passed to server';
}

uploadFile();
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="update-form" id="add-file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="image">Product image</label>
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" multiple="multiple">
    <div class="hidden-holder">
        <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="file">
    </div>
    <div class="submit-holder">
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the passed argument?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Which passed argument are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Direct file upload from ajax only works for new browser.insteat of using direct ajax use this plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#add-file').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Upload Done!"); 
     }); 
});
```

you dont have to change anything of your html.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let name = this.files[0].name;
  let extension = this.files[0].type;
  let date = new Date();
  getBase64(this.files[0], function(base64) {
    ajax(
      'POST',
      'Index.aspx/UploadFile',
      JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        extension: extension,
        date: date,
        data: base64
      }),
      function() {
        console.log(JSON.parse(this.response));
        alert('Uploaded!');
      });
  });
});

function getBase64(file, call) {
  let fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  fr.onload = function(data) {
    call(btoa(this.result));
  }
}

function ajax(method, url, data, call) {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.timeout = 10000;
  request.addEventListener('load', call);
  request.open(method, url);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  request.setRequestHeader('DataType', 'json');
  request.send(data);
}
```

```html
<label>
    Select a file...
    <input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
</label>

<?php
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $data = $_POST['Data'];
    $extension = $_POST['Extension'];
    $date = $_POST['Date'];
    echo 'yep!'
?>
```

Comment: You can check out an complete example how to upload a file with AJAX. You'll see it is easy to adapting at your needs. https://github.com/Spookypeak/Uploading-files---AJAX---ASP.Net

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.